# Need assistance with deprecated code

Tags: ios, uitableview, deprecated

This is what my code looks like now:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSLog(@"index %d %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);
  BSTableViewCell *cell =
  (BSTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StoryList"];
  if (cell == nil) {
    // Create a new cell. CGRectZero allows the cell to determine the appropriate size.
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"StoryList"] autorelease]; //***
    CGRect startingRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 60.0);
    cell =
    [[[BSTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:startingRect
                        reuseIdentifier:@"StoryList"] autorelease]; //***
```

But I'm getting the following error for the marked line:

> /Users/Alex/xCode Projects/FiveMins_1.2(WAV)/Classes/BSGameViewController.m:120:10: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'BSTableViewCell *' from 'UITableViewCell *'

And the following error for the second marked line:

> /Users/Alex/xCode Projects/FiveMins_1.2(WAV)/Classes/BSGameViewController.m:120:38: 'initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 3.0

I'm new at this and that I had someone help me program the initial program, but how do I address these issues?

Comment: [Looking at the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW32), it points out which method should be used; `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Comment: sorry man but you explain your problem very bad start to rewrite everything like more code and a good title for your problem

Comment: And what is with the 3 asterisks all over the place? Is that in your **real** code?

Comment: @MikeD I think it's an attempt to make the lines bold

Answer (score 1):

The first error is easy. Don't create a UITableViewCell, create one of your custom cells:

```
cell = [[[BSTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                               reuseIdentifier:@"StoryList"] autorelease];
```

The same goes for the second error. Don't use initWithFrame: reuseIdentifier:. Use initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: instead, and implement that initializer in your custom cell class.

You might not even need the if (cell == nil) block any more, if you're using storyboards and provide a cell identifier for the table view. In that case the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ALWAYS provides a valid cell, even if it needs to create one.

I see that you have autorelease calls in your code. The FIRST thing you should do is run an ARC conversion on your code. ARC is awesome, and eliminates 95%+ of all memory bugs in people's code.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I really appreciate the thorough explanation despite the obvious and irrelevant issues of my asterisk. @MikeD is correct that it was a really weak attempt at bolding the lines in question. I'm not a great programmer. I had someone else write the code for me and I can't get in touch with him after repeated attempts. I'd gladly pay the guy to fix my "ish" if he would respond to my emails, but I going to try to fix them (and learn Xcode in the process) I'm on own.

Comment: I'll admit this is very much over my head, but the app has been a big success and I want to keep it going. I can't find the original programmer, so I have two choices: Continue to ask questions until I figure this out while simultaneously annoying people like @MikeD or, hire a new programmer.

I prefer the first option, since I love a challenge & learning, but I would also love to get this app fixed, uploaded for iOS7 before iPhone 10 is out.

Duncan, I'd like to discuss working with you to update my code. If you're not interested, can you tell me how to run an ARC conversion on my code?